# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'profilePicUrl') at Home.js:110:1, at Array.map (<anonymous>), at Home (Home.js:102:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

The following error is of home page of react project after the signin process, the home page gets blank and then it gives null properties error in profilePicUrl image.

```html
return (
  <div className='home-container'>
    // error
    {posts.map((post) => {
      return (
        <div className='card home-card' key={post._id}>
          <h5 style={{ padding: '10px' }}>
            {/* console.log("post data", post); */}
            <img
                className='profilePic'
                // error
                src={post?.author.profilePicUrl}
                alt='Profile Picture'
            />
            <Link
                to={
                  post.author._id !== state._id
                  ? '/profile/' + post.author._id
                  : '/profile'
                }>
              {post.author.fullName}
            </Link>
```

Comment: You'll need to use optional chaining on accessing `author` - `post?.author?.profilePicUrl` because `post?.author` may be `undefined`.

Comment: @OriDrori The error talks about `null` and not `undefined`

Comment: Yes @Andreas you are right and i had tried chaining earlier.

Comment: Optional chaining works with `null` as well.

Comment: What ever `post` is, its `author` property is `null` so you have to find the reason for that.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes, but the error tells us that `.author` is `null` which is not possible when `post` would be `undefined` or `null` hence _"because `post?.author` may be `undefined`"_ is not relevant for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As user Ori Drori pointed out, try adding

```js
src={post?.author?.profilePicUrl}
```

As sometimes the author might not be loaded when react tries to access it, or it might be undefined. Also make sure your post object actually has a profilePicUrl.